# querySelector to find label in pure JS

Tags: javascript

Strictly using JS, I want to select a `label` element and add a class.

```
document.querySelector('[for=foobar]').className = "foo";
```

What should go in the `querySelector` to find `<label for="foobar">`?

The error I'm getting is **Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute query: '[for=foobar]' is not a valid selector.**

---

Ok, I actually solved it by adding quotes around `foobar`, so it reads:

```
document.querySelector('[for="foobar"]').className = "foo";
```

Comment: What happens when you do what you have? Or did you mean `document.querySelector('label[for=foobar]')`

Comment: works here http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ6Uu/

Comment: Quite strange as `[for=foobar]` is a valid CSS selector in CSS 2.1 and 3. "Attribute values must be CSS identifiers or strings." here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're looking for a `<label>` tag specifically, you would use:

```
document.querySelector('label[for="foobar"]').className = "foo";
```

The selector that you have will select the first element *of any tag* that has the given `for` attribute.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/f53A4/